# Why there is a PHP Warning for this code and how to prevent this from mysql injections?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in my file.
It reurns nothing but blank.. when I check error log file I see this:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

.

```
 <?php
    include "dbfilepath";
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd, $db_name);
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    ?>
```

why is that?
for me it looks all fine..

and how to secure this simple code from sql injections?

Comment: try to `echo $sql = "SELECT FROM users WHERE username='$username'";` to check it valid or not. I think you are not getting `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: The manual states that it can return boolean. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: use prepared statements to avoid sql injection rather than embedding variables directly in the sql

Comment: See whether a mysql error occured - that might be the reason for mysqli_query returning a boolean

Comment: @duskwuff go on, make the next move and vote to close it with whatever reason you find more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

you forgot to set something to `select`

to secure it you need to use prepared statements for the variable `$username`

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer due to less reputation.

Firstly , you have incorrect syntax for query in select because you don't identify which col name  you want to select like users_name or etc . if you get all records your just write with '*'

"SELECT * FROM users...";

or other answer by the using of prepared statements IN 'PDO' you save from SQL injection because through prepared statements you query will be with secure param .